# USB Serial reset every 15 minutes [Win 10]

Tags: windows, usb, reset, break, mbed

I am developing on an ARM Mbed board which connects to my Windows laptop over USB.  I've just moved to a new Dell laptop running Win 10 [from a Dell laptop running Win 7] and I find that the laptop resets my development board every 15 minutes.

There are two things that will cause the ARM Mbed board to reset:

- powering down/up the USB connection
- sending "break" via the USB serial driver.

When the reset occurs there is nothing of note in the Windows event logs.  I have all of the "allow Windows to power me down" boxes *unticked* on the USB hubs in System devices and in the Control Panel power management options.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I (a) debug what's going on or (b) fix/workaround the problem?  I've not yet tried connecting via a powered USB hub, will do that next...

Comment: It _looks_ as though this may be caused by the Dell Support Assist Agent interacting badly with the ST Microelectronics USB driver for the board.  Having uninstalled this I believe the problem has gone away, but I'll leave it a little longer to be completely sure.

Comment: I have not faced any issue with Windows 10 regarding USB Serial. Have you tried changing the USB cable?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using a FRDM-K64F running mBed and communicating over a USB COM port to a Windows 7 Dell machine. The communication would sometimes drop out. As @Rob suggested, uninstalling the Dell Support Assist Agent completely fixed the issue.

Just adding this answer as it was very difficult to find any information using google.

Answer (score 0):

Another note in support of this solution for google...

I have a Dell 5480 running Windows 10, and started using from ST Nucleo boards on it. I've used the exact same boards at work, with no problems. Every 15minutes or so the board was reset.

I tried disabling the Dell Support Assist services but this did not seem to fix the problem.

Removing the programs did make the Nucleo work.